# Foreign key on different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a images table:

Images

- image_id
- image_type ('foo', 'bar')
- type_id

How can I create a foreign key so if the `image_type` is `foo`, `type_id` should relate to `foo` table, if `image_type` is `bar` to `bar` table.

Comment: Perhaps the best bet is to have a rethink as this will not work

Comment: I think this is a very reasonable request and almost easily possible in MySQL (and possible in other relational databases).

Comment: Why isn't image_type functionally dependent on type_id?

Comment: Alternatively, create two tables `foo_image (image_id, type_id)` and `bar_image (image_id, type_id)` with corresponding foreign keys and set `image_id` in these tables as as foreign key to the `images` table. You can even left out the `image_type` column then.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to create a supertype. In SQL this is best modeled like below (IMO at least). My apologies if the syntax isn't quite right for MySQL. I usually use MS SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE Image_Types (
    image_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    image_type    CHAR(3) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_Image_Types_image_type CHECK (image_type IN ('Foo', 'Bar')),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Image_Types PRIMARY KEY (image_type_id, image_type)
)

CREATE TABLE Foo (
    image_type_id            INT          NOT NULL,
    image_type               CHAR(3)      NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_Foo_image_type CHECK (image_type IN ('Foo')),
    some_foo_specific_column VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Foo PRIMARY KEY (image_type_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Foo_ImageTypes FOREIGN KEY (image_type_id, image_type) REFERENCES Image_Types (image_type_id, image_type)
)

CREATE TABLE Bar (
    image_type_id            INT          NOT NULL,
    image_type               CHAR(3)      NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_Bar_image_type CHECK (image_type IN ('Bar')),
    some_bar_specific_column VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Bar PRIMARY KEY (image_type_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Bar_ImageTypes FOREIGN KEY (image_type_id, image_type) REFERENCES Image_Types (image_type_id, image_type)
)

CREATE TABLE Images (
    image_id      INT NOT NULL,
    image_type    CHAR(3) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CHK_Images_image_type CHECK (image_type IN ('Foo', 'Bar')),
    image_type_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Images PRIMARY KEY (image_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Images_ImageTypes FOREIGN KEY (image_type_id, image_type) REFERENCES Image_Types (image_type_id, image_type)
)
```

An alternative approach, if your RDBMS supports it, is to use filtered indexed views on `Image_Types` and then have your FKs in `Foo` and `Bar` point at those views. That allows you to eliminate the `image_type` column from some of your tables. Some people prefer the above pattern even when filtered indexed views are available though.